# COALESCE failing following CTE Deletion. (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, constraints, common-table-expression, coalesce

PostgreSQL 11.1 PgAdmin 4.1

This works *some of the time*:

```
BEGIN;
    SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;

    WITH _in(trx, lastname, firstname, birthdate, old_disp, old_medname, old_sig, old_form, new_disp, new_medname, new_sig, new_form, new_refills)  AS (
            VALUES ('2001-06-07 00:00:00'::timestamp, 
                    UPPER(TRIM('JONES')), UPPER(TRIM('TOM')), '1952-12-30'::date,
                    64::integer, 
                    LOWER(TRIM('adipex 37.5mg tab')), LOWER(TRIM('one tab po qd')), LOWER(TRIM('tab')),
                    63::integer,
                    LOWER(TRIM('adipex 37.5mg tab')), LOWER(TRIM('one tab po qd')), LOWER(TRIM('tab')),
                    33::integer
                    )
            ),
        _s AS (                 -- RESOLVE ALL SURROGATE KEYS.
                SELECT n.*, d1.recid as old_medication_recid, d2.recid as new_medication_recid, pt.recid as patient_recid
                FROM _in n
                JOIN medications d1 ON (n.old_medname, n.old_sig, n.old_form) = (d1.medname, d1.sig, d1.form)
                JOIN medications d2 ON (n.new_medname, n.new_sig, n.new_form) = (d2.medname, d2.sig, d2.form)
                JOIN patients pt ON (pt.lastname, pt.firstname, pt.birthdate) = (n.lastname, n.firstname, n.birthdate)
        ),
         _t AS (               -- REMOVE CONFLICTING RECORD, IF ANY.
                DELETE FROM rx r
                USING _s n
                WHERE (r.trx::date, r.disp, r.patient_recid, r.medication_recid)=(n.trx::date, n.new_disp, n.patient_recid, n.new_medication_recid)
                RETURNING r.*
            ),
          _u  AS(               -- GET NEW SURROGATE KEY.
                SELECT COALESCE(_t.recid, r.recid) as target_recid, r.recid as old_recid
                FROM _s n
                JOIN rx r ON (r.trx, r.disp, r.patient_recid, r.medication_recid) = (n.trx, n.old_disp, n.patient_recid, n.old_medication_recid)
                LEFT JOIN _t ON (_t.trx::date, _t.disp, _t.patient_recid, _t.medication_recid) = (n.trx::date, n.new_disp, n.patient_recid, n.new_medication_recid)
            )                                   
        UPDATE rx r           -- UPDATE ORIGINAL RECORD WITH NEW VALUES.
        SET disp = n.new_disp, medication_recid = n.new_medication_recid, refills = n.new_refills, recid = _u.target_recid
        FROM _s n, _u
        WHERE r.recid = _u.old_recid
        RETURNING r.*;

COMMIT;
```

Where table rx is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE phoenix.rx
(
    recid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('rx_recid_seq'::regclass),
    trx timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    disp integer NOT NULL,
    refills integer,
    tprinted timestamp without time zone,
    tstop timestamp without time zone,
    modified timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
    patient_recid integer NOT NULL,
    medication_recid integer NOT NULL,
    dposted date NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_rx_recid PRIMARY KEY (recid),
    CONSTRAINT rx_unique UNIQUE (dposted, disp, patient_recid, medication_recid)

        DEFERRABLE,
    CONSTRAINT rx_medication_fk FOREIGN KEY (medication_recid)
        REFERENCES phoenix.medications (recid) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
        DEFERRABLE,
    CONSTRAINT rx_patients FOREIGN KEY (patient_recid)
        REFERENCES phoenix.patients (recid) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
)
```

After many hours, it is found that the "Delete.." of a conflicting record works as expected, but the "COALESCE" STATEMENT seems to fail when deciding on the new surrogate key (primary key) of rx.recid -- it does not seem to receive the result of the delete. (Or maybe the timing is wrong???)

Any help would be most appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [is documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

> The sub-statements in `WITH` are executed concurrently with each other and with the main query. Therefore, when using data-modifying statements in `WITH`, the order in which the specified updates actually happen is unpredictable. All the statements are executed with the same *snapshot* (see [Chapter 13](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/mvcc.html), so they cannot “see” one another's effects on the target tables.

Don't use the same table twice in a statement with a CTE if it occurs in a DML statement. Rather, use `DELETE ... RETURNING` and use the returned values in the other parts of the statement.

If you cannot rewrite the statement like that, use more than one statement instead of putting everything into a single CTE.

Comment: That would explain whats happening. Suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: I added general hints. Your special case is too complicated for me to penetrate.

Answer (score 0):

@LaurenzAlbe is totally correct in his answer. Below is a working solution to my problem. There are a few things to note:

1. The unique constraint is formed on a column in rx defined as a date and created by a trigger on update/insert that casts the timestamp of trx to a date: as in trx::date. For reasons I am not clear on, using r.trx::date in place of r.dposted leads to many records being identified and not the one record I want.  Not sure why???. So the first fix was to use r.dposted, not r.trx::date.
2. Although the cte's are designed to be independent of each other, by using "RETURNING..." and incorporating the cte's in a step-wise fashion, one can be built upon another to obtain a final result set.
   The working code is:

   ```
   WITH _in(trx, lastname, firstname, birthdate, old_disp, old_medname, old_sig, old_form, new_disp, new_medname, new_sig, new_form, new_refills)  AS (
               VALUES ('2001-06-07 00:00:00'::timestamp, 
                       UPPER(TRIM('smith')), UPPER(TRIM('john')), '1957-12-30'::date,
                       28::integer, 
                       LOWER(TRIM('test')), LOWER(TRIM('i am sig')), LOWER(TRIM('tab')),
                       28::integer,
                       LOWER(TRIM('test 1')), LOWER(TRIM('i am sig')), LOWER(TRIM('tab')),
                       8::integer
                       )
               ),  
             _m AS (
                   SELECT n.*, d1.recid as old_medication_recid, d2.recid as new_medication_recid, pt.recid as patient_recid
                   FROM _in n
                   JOIN patients pt ON (pt.lastname, pt.firstname, pt.birthdate) = (n.lastname, n.firstname, n.birthdate)
                   JOIN medications d1 ON (n.old_medname, n.old_sig, n.old_form) = (d1.medname, d1.sig, d1.form)
                   LEFT JOIN medications d2 ON (n.new_medname, n.new_sig, n.new_form) = (d2.medname, d2.sig, d2.form)              
             ),              
             _t AS (               -- REMOVE CONFLICTING RECORD, IF ANY.
                   DELETE FROM rx r
                   USING _m
                   WHERE (r.dposted, r.disp, r.patient_recid, r.medication_recid) = (_m.trx::date,_m.new_disp, _m.patient_recid, _m.new_medication_recid)
                   RETURNING r.*
               ),
             _s AS (               -- GET NEW SURROGATE KEY
                   SELECT _m.*, r1.recid as old_recid, r2.recid as new_recid, COALESCE(r2.recid, r1.recid) as target_recid
                   FROM _m
                   JOIN rx r1 ON (r1.dposted, r1.disp, r1.patient_recid, r1.medication_recid) = (_m.trx::date,_m.old_disp, _m.patient_recid, _m.old_medication_recid)
                   LEFT JOIN rx r2 ON (r2.dposted, r2.disp, r2.patient_recid, r2.medication_recid) = (_m.trx::date,_m.new_disp, _m.patient_recid, _m.new_medication_recid)
                   LEFT JOIN _t ON (_t.recid = r2.recid)
             )
           UPDATE rx               -- UPDATE ORIGINAL RECORD WITH NEW VALUES.
           SET disp = _s.new_disp, medication_recid = _s.new_medication_recid, refills = _s.new_refills, recid = _s.target_recid
           FROM _s 
           WHERE rx.recid = _s.old_recid
           RETURNING rx.*;

   COMMIT;
   ```

Hope this helps somebody.